# Javascript - Array.repeat limitations?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I'm looking to create a new array, composed of the original array contents repeated 3 times. For example:

```
var array = ["red", "green", "blue"];
newArray = ["red red red", "green green green", "blue blue blue"];
```

My code so far:

```
var triples = myArray.map(function(){
  for (x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
    return myArray[x].repeat(3);
  };
});
console.log(triples);
```

But this only returns

```
triples = ["redredred", "redredred", "redredred"];
```

Any suggestions for a newbie?

Comment: return will exit that function on the first run, ex. x = 0

Comment: [String.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) doesn't allow for inserting join characters. You'll have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a simple function to do this:

```
var triples = function(xs) {
  return xs.map(function(x) {
    return [x,x,x].join(' ')
  })
}
```

You can abstract it a bit more, as a transformation to use with `map`, and allow any number of repetitions:

```
var repeat = function(n) {
  return function(x) {
    return Array.apply(0, {length:n})
      .map(function(){return x})
      .join(' ')
  }
}

['foo','bar','lol'].map(repeat(3))
//^ ['foo foo foo', 'bar bar bar', 'lol lol lol']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an obnoxiously simple way of repeating all elements 3 times:

```
["red", "green", "blue"].map(  [].join.bind(['',' ',' ',''])   );
// == ["red red red", "green green green", "blue blue blue"]
```

this method also doesn't need "".repeat(), which is not universally supported yet.

another bonus: if a number, null, or other non-string sneaks in the array it won't break.

if you want it re-usable,  that's easy enough:

```
 var repeater = [].join.bind(['',' ',' ','']) ;

 ["red", "green", "blue"].map( repeater );
 // == ["red red red", "green green green", "blue blue blue"]

 [1,2,3,4,5].map( repeater );
 // == ["1 1 1", "2 2 2", "3 3 3", "4 4 4", "5 5 5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use `map` *and* the loop. I guess you wanted either

```
var triples = myArray.map(function(str){
  return str.repeat(3);
});
console.log(triples);
```

or

```
var triples = [];
for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
  triples[x] = myArray[x].repeat(3);
}
console.log(triples);
```

---

However, as @digitalfresh mentioned in the comments, [`String::repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) doesn't insert the spaces, so you rather want to use `(" "+…).repeat(3).slice(1)` or use the functions presented by @dandavis or @elclanrs. Or, since you seem to use an Ecmascript 6 method anyway, you could do `Array.from({length:3}, ()=>…).join(" ")`.